# C++ Template Assignment Operator overload -- assign primitive type to object?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible in C++ to overload the assignment operator for an object to accept primitive types?

For example

```
template< typename T> 
  class Variable
  {
     ...
     Variable<T>& operator=( const Variable<T>& )
     {
       mValue = 0;
       return &this;
     }
  }

  int l = 3;
  Variable<int> intVar();
  intVar = l;
```

If I try to do this, I receive the following error

```
error: non-object type 'Variable<int> ()' is not assignable
```

I feel as if I'm missing something obvious -- I though this was possible with C++?

Comment: I should also add, if I change the assignment operator to Variable<T>& operator=( const T val ) it also fails

Answer (score 5):

You've encountered a "vexing parse". `Variable<int> intVar();` declares a function, not an object; the `()` at the end of the type specification in the error message indicates a function type.

You want `Variable<int> intVar;` to declare and default-initialise an object.

If you need value-initialisation rather than default-initialisation then your choices are:

```
Variable<int> intVar{};                 // C++11 or later
Variable<int> intVar = Variable<int>(); // Historic dialects
```

Comment: Also notable is that this fix will still not make the assignment work since there is no conversion path from `int` to `Variable<int>` in the current code.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: I'm assuming that that (along with the `public` specifier) is in the part elided to `...`. This is just an explanation for the reported error.

Comment: no arguments, just stating that I'm not sure what causes that specific error in which specific compiler - it could be related since it also makes variable invalid for that specific assignment. Would've helped if we'd gotten a specific line with the error.

Comment: +1 for using the term "vexing parse".  It comes up every now and then and I always struggle with what to call this issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone -- This solved the issue for me. I love the "vexing parse" term as well -- I'll be sure to remember it. Again, I really appreciate it :)